# Edge Animate: Play animation with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, adobe-edge

I've disabled the autoplay-option in the Edge Animate Composition.
Now I would like to bind these animation with the waypoints.js so i need to call the animation by javascript.

This is my HTML

```
<div id="StageTwo" class="EDGE-4436041"></div>
```

This is the Javascript

```
<script>
   AdobeEdge.loadComposition('animation_bereitstellung', 'EDGE-4436041', {
    scaleToFit: "both",
bScaleToParent: "true",
    centerStage: "horizontal",
    minW: "0px",
    maxW: "undefined",
    width: "650px",
    height: "463px"
}, {"dom":{}}, {"style":{"${symbolSelector}":{"isStage":"true","rect":["undefined","undefined","500px","356px"],"fill":["rgba(255,255,255,1)"]}},"dom":{}});
</script>
```

The problem: I've multiple animations on a single site.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this is to call the Adobe Edge API with a bootstrapCallback in a manner similar to the following:

```
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
  element: document.getElementById('basic-waypoint'),
  handler: function() {

    window.AdobeEdge.bootstrapCallback(function(compId) {

        var comp = AdobeEdge.getComposition("EDGE-4436041"); 

        //either to play the stage
        var stage = comp.getStage().play();

        //or to play a symbol inside the stage
        var mySymbol = comp.getStage().getSymbol("symbol");
        mySymbol.play();

    });

  }

});
```

Hope that helps!